# Parse JSON nested arrays in Excel in specific way

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing

I got some help and I wasn't sure if I should continue this in the original question or start a new one since technically it is a new question (I chose new but let me know what you guys prefer for next time).

I figured out how to parse the standard set of information into different columns. I'm having trouble getting the nested arrays to parse. It gives a ***runtime error 5*** when it gets to that part of the code. The array under `customfields` needs to be parsed into columns but the estimate lines array contains part/pricing information that needs to be parsed into rows.

Here is the code I've written so far:

```vb
Sub doJSON()

    Dim JSON As Object
    ' Dim CustomFields As Dictionary
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Dim strJSON As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Item As Variant

    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\jb\VBVA Team Dropbox\Y&M \Owner Files\auto update vba macro\sb data.txt")
    strJSON = TS.ReadAll
    Set JSON = ParseJson(strJSON)
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet20")
    i = 3
    ws.Cells(2, 1) = "WorkOrderNumber"
    ws.Cells(2, 2) = "EstimateNumber"
    ws.Cells(2, 3) = "EstimateDate"
    ws.Cells(2, 4) = "WonOrLostDate"
    ws.Cells(2, 5) = "ScheduledTime"
    ws.Cells(2, 6) = "EstimatedDuration"
    ws.Cells(2, 7) = "Customer Name"
    ws.Cells(2, 8) = "Contact name"
    ws.Cells(2, 9) = "Location Name"
    ' ws.Cells(2, 10) = "GeoCoordinates : Latitude"
    ' ws.Cells(2, 11) = "GeoCoordinates : Longitude"
    ws.Cells(2, 12) = "MarketingCampaign"
    ws.Cells(2, 13) = "Team"
    ws.Cells(2, 14) = "WorkOrderDate"
    ws.Cells(2, 15) = "DateFinished"
    ws.Cells(2, 16) = "ScheduledTime"
    ws.Cells(2, 17) = "EstimatedDuration"
    ws.Cells(2, 18) = "Notes"
    ws.Cells(2, 19) = "PrivateNotes"
    ws.Cells(2, 20) = "SalesRepresentative"
    ws.Cells(2, 21) = "Description"
    ws.Cells(2, 22) = "Status"
    ws.Cells(2, 23) = "IsInvoiced"
    ws.Cells(2, 24) = "CreatedBy"
    ws.Cells(2, 25) = "CreatedOn"
    ws.Cells(2, 26) = "UpdatedOn"
    ws.Cells(2, 27) = "UpdatedBy"
    ws.Cells(2, 28) = "Version"
    ws.Cells(2, 29) = "CC Referred By"
    For Each Item In JSON("Data")
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = Item("WorkOrderNumber")
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = Item("EstimateNumber")
        ws.Cells(i, 3) = Item("EstimateDate")
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = Item("WonOrLostDate")
        ws.Cells(i, 5) = Item("ScheduledTime")
        ws.Cells(i, 6) = Item("EstimatedDuration")
        ws.Cells(i, 7) = Item("Customer")("Name")
        ws.Cells(i, 8) = Item("Conact")("Name")
        ws.Cells(i, 9) = Item("Location")("Name")
' THis next 2 line gives me a type mismatch error and i cant figure out why
        ' ws.Cells(i, 10) = Item("GeoCoordinates")("Latitude")
        ' ws.Cells(i, 11) = Item("GeoCoordinates")("Longitude")
        ws.Cells(i, 12) = Item("MarketingCampaign")("Name")
        ws.Cells(i, 13) = Item("Team")("name")
        ws.Cells(i, 14) = Item("WorkOrderDate")
        ws.Cells(i, 15) = Item("DateFinished")
        ws.Cells(i, 16) = Item("ScheduledTime")
        ws.Cells(i, 17) = Item("EstimatedDuration")
        ws.Cells(i, 18) = Item("Notes")
        ws.Cells(i, 19) = Item("PrivateNotes")
        ws.Cells(i, 20) = Item("SalesRepresentative")("Name")
        ws.Cells(i, 21) = Item("Description")
        ws.Cells(i, 22) = Item("Status")
        ws.Cells(i, 23) = Item("IsInvoiced")
        ws.Cells(i, 24) = Item("Metadata")("CreatedBy")
        ws.Cells(i, 25) = Item("Metadata")("CreatedOn")
        ws.Cells(i, 26) = Item("Metadata")("UpdatedOn")
        ws.Cells(i, 27) = Item("Metadata")("UpdatedBy")
        ws.Cells(i, 28) = Item("Metadata")("Version")
        i = i + 1
    Next
    For Each Item In JSON("Data")("CustomFields")
        ' this is the part of the code that gives me a runtime error 5 . i need it to pull name data from custom field
        ws.Cells(i, 29) = Item("name")(1)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    ' this next part of the code i dont even know where to start.i need to add the material and price information for each work order item and repeat all the other information like work order number for each different material/price added to the table.

End Sub
```

I included a sample of the json file and an example of what I want the end result to look like:

```
{
    "TotalCount": 5136,
    "Data": [
        {
            "WorkOrderId": null,
            "WorkOrderNumber": null,
            "Id": 24668520,
            "Metadata": {
                "CreatedBy": "**blah**.com",
                "CreatedOn": "2020-01-17T21:02:11",
                "UpdatedOn": "2020-01-27T14:36:42",
                "UpdatedBy": "blah.com",
                "Version": 6
            },
            "ExternalSystemId": null
        },
        {
            "EstimateNumber": "EST 12523",
            "Customer": {
                "Inactive": false,
                "Id": 8656822,
                "Name": "blahe"
            },
            "Location": {
                "Id": 9314838,
                "Name": "Primary"
            },
            "GeoCoordinates": {
                "Latitude": 36.7926476,
                "Longitude": -76.25019759999998
            },
            "CoordinatesCaptured": true,
            "Contact": {
                "Id": 9111128,
                "Name": "blah"
            },
            "ThirdPartyBillPayer": null,
            "IsMarketingCampaignSetByLead": false,
            "MarketingCampaign": {
                "Id": 115753,
                "Name": "Web Call In"
            },
            "JobCategory": null,
            "SalesRepresentative": {
                "Id": 242299,
                "Name": "**blah**"
            },
            "DefaultEquipment": null,
            "Description": "Guard Estimate",
            "Status": "Finished",
            "Branch": {
                "Id": 145945,
                "Name": "blah-VA"
            },
            "Team": {
                "Id": 188466,
                "Name": "blah"
            },
            "TeamMembers": [
                {
                    "EmployeeId": 242299,
                    "UserId": 179578,
                    "FirstName": "blah",
                    "LastName": "blah",
                    "Email": "blah.com",
                    "Title": null
                }
            ],
            "ConfirmationStatus": "None",
            "EstimateDate": "2020-01-21T00:00:00",
            "WonOrLostDate": null,
            "ScheduledTime": 930,
            "EstimatedDuration": 60,
            "ArrivalWindow": 60,
            "EarliestArrival": null,
            "LatestDeparture": null,
            "Notes": "\nGUTTER - NO EXISTING GUTTERS\nClient requests new 5\" ( white) seamless gutters and downspouts to prevent further soil erosion and water damage to foundation of home, caused by lack of functioning gutter system. 5 year labor and 20 year materials warranty included.",
            "PrivateNotes": "Solutionist Instructions: 1/17/20- Gutter Guard Estimate- A lot of trees around him he cant keep up with the cleaning- he needs 3:30 or after he runs a daycare- TB\nLlyods e-mail keeps bouncing back we confirmed its correct still not going thru- he uses (2) -(o) in his first name but (1) -(o) in his e-mail- I sent text confirmation e-mail- TB\n\nHouse Color: Orange Brick \nDoes Customer Have Dogs: YES- small\n\nDate Estimate Scheduled & Email Sent:\n\nScheduling Instructions: \n\nDate Called & Emailed to Schedule:\nDate of Service Text & Email: \n\nBilling Instructions:\nDeposit $ \nBalance Due $ \n\nInstaller Instructions: \n\n\nInstaller Notes:\nPROS:\n\nCONS:\n\nWAS PAYMENT TAKEN?",
            "InvoiceNotes": null,
            "ReminderType": "None",
            "ReminderValue": 0,
            "ReminderMessage": "",
            "EstimateLines": [
                {
                    "Id": 30130758,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688230,
                        "SKU": "2X3­PO­ALU",
                        "Name": "2 3/4\" Aluminum Pop Outlet",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 1,
                    "Quantity": 11,
                    "Description": "Pop Outlets are snapped into the gutter opening that leads into the downspout. The downspout is secured directly to the outlet.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130757,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688633,
                        "SKU": "5K­HH­ALU",
                        "Name": "5\" Aluminum Hidden Hanger",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 2,
                    "Quantity": 120,
                    "Description": "Hidden Hangers are used to secure a gutter to a structure.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130755,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688648,
                        "SKU": "5K­ISM­ALU­ WHI",
                        "Name": "5\" Aluminum White K-Style Inside Strip Miter",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 20,
                    "Quantity": 3,
                    "Description": "An inside strip miter is used to create a smooth transition between two gutters that intersect at a 90░ angle in the inside valley of a structure.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30131039,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688246,
                        "SKU": "2X3-­BE­-ALU­-WHT",
                        "Name": "2x3\" Aluminum White B Elbow",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 5,
                    "Quantity": 4,
                    "Description": "B Elbows are typically used to attach a downspout to the side of a structure. They are also used on other areas of a downspout enabling it to conform to the contour of a structure.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30131036,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688646,
                        "SKU": "5K­IBYM­ALU­ WHI",
                        "Name": "5\" Aluminum White K-Style Inside Bay Miter",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 20,
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Description": "An inside bay miter is used to create a smooth transition between two gutters that intersect at a 45░ angle in the inside valley of a structure.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30131051,
                    "ParentId": null,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688793,
                        "SKU": "ONE-24-GUARD-KIT",
                        "Name": "Items for Installation",
                        "Type": "Bundle"
                    },
                    "Price": 2220,
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Description": "See product details below",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30131052,
                    "ParentId": 30131051,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688663,
                        "SKU": "5­ONE­24­ GUARD",
                        "Name": "5'' One Gutter Guard",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 12,
                    "Quantity": 185,
                    "Description": "One Guard gutter protection is an approved gutter guard for The Brothers that Just do Gutters. OneGuard gutter protection is designed with a .027\" gauge thick 3105 H14/24 aluminum chassis and painted with polyester paint .7 mil thick (both sides). The One Guard 24 mesh is fabricated from surgical stainless steel 24 mesh with .0075\" wire diameter. Self­ supporting with NO substrate, it creates an even higher flow choice. The One Guard Product helps strengthen the entire gutter system. The chassis dam of the One Gutter Guard acts as a \"culvert\" to capture the bulk of the roof water in the first zone to minimize the migration towards the front of the system. Dam also strengthens the chassis and supports the insert in snow loads or other situations. All of these features make One Gutter Guard an excellent product to keep your gutters free of any interior clog.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30131061,
                    "ParentId": null,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1744982,
                        "SKU": "DISC",
                        "Name": "Discount",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": -555,
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Description": "Gutter and guard discount of $555",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30131054,
                    "ParentId": 30131051,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688764,
                        "SKU": "GTR­CL­ GUARDS",
                        "Name": "Interior Gutter Cleaning ­ with Guard Installation",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 0,
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Description": "No charge gutter cleaning with guard installation. Cleaning of the interior of a gutter system, elbows and downspouts either by hand or leaf blower. All leaves and debris will be discarded in nearby woods or completely removed from the premises.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130933,
                    "ParentId": null,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688787,
                        "SKU": "5K-ALU-WHI-KIT",
                        "Name": "Items for Installation",
                        "Type": "Bundle"
                    },
                    "Price": 2019,
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Description": "See product details below",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130754,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688650,
                        "SKU": "5K­OBYM­ALU­ WHI",
                        "Name": "5\" Aluminum White K-Style Outside Bay Miter",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 20,
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Description": "An outside bay miter is used to create a smooth transition between two gutters that intersect at a 45░ angle on the outside corner of a structure.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130756,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688649,
                        "SKU": "5K­LEC­ALU­ WHI",
                        "Name": "5\" Aluminum White K-Style Left End Cap",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 2,
                    "Quantity": 11,
                    "Description": "A left end cap is secured to the left side of an open\ngutter just past the end of the roof. It is crimped and sealed to prevent leaking.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130759,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688245,
                        "SKU": "2X3­-AE­-ALU­-WHT",
                        "Name": "2x3\" Aluminum White A Elbow",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 5,
                    "Quantity": 22,
                    "Description": "A Elbows are typically used to attach a downspoutto the face of a structure. They are also used on other areas of a downspout enabling it to conform to the contour of a structure.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130760,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688247,
                        "SKU": "2X3­-DS­ALU­-WHI",
                        "Name": "2x3\" Aluminum White Downspout",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 5,
                    "Quantity": 100,
                    "Description": "Downspouts carry rainwater from the gutter to the ground.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130761,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688645,
                        "SKU": "5K­ALU­WHI",
                        "Name": "5\" Aluminum White K-Style Gutter",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 5,
                    "Quantity": 190,
                    "Description": "K­Style Gutters are designed to carry rainwater from the roof to the ground, protecting a structure from water damage. The K­Style design offers optimal performance and is the industry standard for gutter installation. The color is baked into this .032 heavy gauge gutter and comes with a 20­year warranty.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130934,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688653,
                        "SKU": "5K­REC­ALU­ WHI",
                        "Name": "5\" Aluminum White K-Style Right End Cap",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 2,
                    "Quantity": 11,
                    "Description": "A right end cap is secured to the right side of an open gutter just past the end of the roof. It is crimped and sealed to prevent leaking.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130935,
                    "ParentId": 30130933,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688250,
                        "SKU": "2X3­UC­ALU­ WHI",
                        "Name": "2x3\" Aluminum White U Clips",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 2,
                    "Quantity": 22,
                    "Description": "U Clips are low profile accessories used to secure a downspout to a structure. The U shape design offers low visibility and superior strength.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30130779,
                    "ParentId": 30131051,
                    "Inventory": {
                        "Id": 1688770,
                        "SKU": "ONE­GUARD­ REALCHECK",
                        "Name": "One Guard Reality Check",
                        "Type": "Product"
                    },
                    "Price": 0,
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Description": "While many of our clients enjoy maintenance free gutters, it is not the reality for everyone. One Gutter Guard Protection is an amazing product designed to keep the inside of your gutters and downspouts clog free. Guards will freeze & you may get icicles. Rain hitting the gutter surface following the profile of the gutter may cause drip. Debris that remains on the guard will need to be removed from time to time with a broom or leaf blower in order to let the water flow into the guard. Roof pitch, design & types of trees will determine potential maintenance of the guard.",
                    "IsTaxable": false,
                    "Tax": null
                }
            ],
            "CustomFields": [
                {
                    "Name": "CC Referred By",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "E3 Electric:",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W3 Yard Sign Posted",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "P2 Materials Checked",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "P3 Photos & Diagrams Included",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W8 Referrals given to Customer",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "E2 Ladders Needed:",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "P4 Priority List",
                    "Value": "False"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "P Material Box",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "E4 Takedown",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W6 Describe Delays",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W7 Final walk around/Payment Taken",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W5 Amount of  Delay Due To Work Obstacles",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W Tools/Materials visually inspected",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "E Roof Pitch",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "E1 Roof Material ",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "CC1 Marketing Source Correction",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "CC4 Estimate Summary Correction",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "S Walk Around Done",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "S1 All Expectations Set In Writing/Photos",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "S2 I Feel Est. Will Close In",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "S3 I went for",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "E5 Movement Difficulty",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "CC3 Time Lost ",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "S4 Est Rating",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "S6 Reason Client Chose our Company",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "S5 Solutionist notes",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W1 Called in Rought",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W2 initial walk around completed",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W4 Safety Concerns/Description",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "W9 Client Rating",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "S7 Follow Up Notes",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "CC5 Reasons for Area of Improvement",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "CC2 Est. Scheduling Area of Improvement",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "P1 Man Hours",
                    "Value": ""
                }
            ],
            "ExternalSystemId": null
        }
    ],
    "Success": true,
    "Error": null
}
```

[image]

UPDATE

I tried the solution proposed in the answer and encountered an issue - I need the parts information located in estimate lines listed out in a column with the associated items like estimate numbers and custom fields repeated. I've included a photo of what it would look like:

[image: expected]

Comment: `Item("Conact")("Name")`  Error probably due to a typo.  You don't have `Conact` in your posted JSON.

Comment: Is the JSON sample posted representing one row of data only? Could you please add more rows for example.

Comment: i tried on the original post but it said it was too long. i'll do it again here.

Comment: You may put the full sample to pastebin and share the link here.

Comment: Also If you run the code with such JSON sample then the lines with `Item("WorkOrderNumber")` and `Item("EstimateNumber")` will give an error, since `WorkOrderNumber` and `EstimateNumber` properties belongs to different objects in the sample. Please provide the right sample for the above VBA code.

Comment: Item 1 only contains `WorkOrderId;WorkOrderNumber;Id;Metadata;ExternalSystemId`, so looking for `Item("Customer")("Name")` will return an error.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zDDt2LV0.... this is the link to as much of the json as i could load.

Comment: omegastripes - i am not getting an error on workordernumber or estimate number. i have provided the requested sample.

Comment: I fixed the sample (added close brackets) to make it valid, and placed here https://pastebin.com/wVtq027R

Comment: I looked up for `"EstimateNumber": "EST 12784"` in the sample https://pastebin.com/wVtq027R and found no such parts like `"Name": "3x4\" Aluminum White A Elbow"` etc. as you specified on the screenshot. Could you please specify the expected output for the actual sample to make data structure clear. Do you need to present each line from `"EstimateLines"` as a separate row? Is there any row should be in results for `"EstimateLines": []`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is VBA example showing how that data could be parsed. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser/blob/master/JSON.bas) and [jsonExt.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser/blob/master/Beta/jsonExt.bas) modules from [VBA JSON parser](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) into the VBA project for JSON processing, and include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"** (take a look [here](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser#deployment) how to import module and add reference).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    ' retrieve json
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://pastebin.com/raw/wVtq027R", True
        .Send
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Dim resp As String
        resp = .ResponseText
    End With
    Dim content
    Dim state As String
    JSON.Parse resp, content, state
    Dim data
    Dim exists
    jsonExt.selectElement content, ".Data", data, exists
    If Not exists Then MsgBox "No data": End
    ' convert CustomFields to conventional format {"propertyName":"propertyValue", ...}
    Dim fieldNames As Dictionary
    Set fieldNames = New Dictionary
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To UBound(data)
        Dim custFields As Dictionary
        Set custFields = New Dictionary
        Dim custField
        For Each custField In data(i)("CustomFields")
            If custField("Value") <> "" Then
                custFields(custField("Name")) = custField("Value")
                fieldNames("CustomFields." & custField("Name")) = ""
            End If
        Next
        Set data(i)("CustomFields") = custFields
    Next
    ' specify fields neccessary to display
    Dim head()
    head = Array("WorkOrderNumber", "EstimateNumber", "EstimateDate", "WonOrLostDate", "ScheduledTime", "EstimatedDuration", "Customer.Name", "Conact.Name", "Location.Name", "GeoCoordinates.Latitude", "GeoCoordinates.Longitude", "MarketingCampaign.Name", "Team.name", "WorkOrderDate", "DateFinished", "ScheduledTime", "EstimatedDuration", "Notes", "PrivateNotes", "SalesRepresentative.Name", "Description", "Status", "IsInvoiced", "Metadata.CreatedBy", "Metadata.CreatedOn", "Metadata.UpdatedOn", "Metadata.UpdatedBy", "Metadata.Version")
    jsonExt.pushItem head, fieldNames.keys(), , False
    ' convert json to arrays
    Dim body()
    jsonExt.toArray data, body, head, True
    ' output arrays to worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Activate
        .Cells.Delete
        With .Cells(1, 1)
            .Resize(1, UBound(head) - LBound(head) + 1).Value = head
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
                    UBound(body, 1) - LBound(body, 1) + 1, _
                    UBound(body, 2) - LBound(body, 2) + 1 _
                ).Value = body
        End With
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

The output for me is as follows:

[image: output]

*BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).*

Comment: the code gives me  ***variable not defined*** errors when i try to run it. I've read and looked over all your parsing answers and the list you sent me with related answers tr try to figure it out myself and i can get past the first errors by adding  
 `Dim JSON As Dictionary    Set JSON = ParseJson(resp)`

Comment: You shouldn't use `Set JSON = ParseJson(resp)`, just create a new blank workbook and follow the steps in the answer. Please read carefully how to import module and add reference.

Comment: i followed the instructions to the letter and copy and pasted the exact same code but it gives me *** no data *** message box i see in the code. any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @YerryBalenzuela I fixed typo in url, please try again.

Comment: hey thanks it works great !  the only thing is i don't know if i explained it well enough in the original post but i need the parts information located in estimate lines listed out in a column with the associated items like estimate numbers and custom fields repeated . ive included a photo of what it would look like.

Comment: @YerryBalenzuela I inserted all the relevant info you provided into update section of the question.